# ANDROID SQLITE- Error for Multiple Update

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to update some value from sqlite database.if i update one columns value that does correctly and when i am trying update multiple value without Primary Key then my activity makes terminate.i will be grateful if could to know the reason of this error.

My Sample Code:

this code Run Well(here i have update only on column)

```
 private void updateData(){
             String fullName=  editText_fullName.getText().toString();
                            String emailAddress= editText_emailAddress.getText().toString();
                            String mobileNo=  editText_mobileNo.getText().toString();
                            String address= editText_address.getText().toString();
                            String voiceCode=button_tackeVoice.getText().toString();
                            String password=editText_password.getText().toString();
            final SQLiteDatabase myDB = openOrCreateDatabase(FeedReaderDbHelper.DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE,
        null);
            updateStringData(myDB, FeedReaderDbHelper.FULL_NAME, fullName);


             }
    private void updateStringData(SQLiteDatabase myDB,String columnName,String data){
                    try {

                        String strSQL = "UPDATE user SET "+columnName+" ='"+data+"' WHERE userName = '"+ userData.userName+"'";

                        myDB.execSQL(strSQL);
                        myDB.close();

                    }catch (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException ex) {

                    }
                }
```

This Code Makes Terrible:(Here i am trying to update multi column)

```
private void updateData(){
     String fullName=  editText_fullName.getText().toString();
                    String emailAddress= editText_emailAddress.getText().toString();
                    String mobileNo=  editText_mobileNo.getText().toString();
                    String address= editText_address.getText().toString();
                    String voiceCode=button_tackeVoice.getText().toString();
                    String password=editText_password.getText().toString();
    final SQLiteDatabase myDB = openOrCreateDatabase(FeedReaderDbHelper.DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    updateStringData(myDB, FeedReaderDbHelper.FULL_NAME, fullName);
                        updateStringData(myDB,FeedReaderDbHelper.EMAIL_ADDRESS,emailAddress);
                        updateStringData(myDB,FeedReaderDbHelper.MOBILE_NO,mobileNo);
                        updateStringData(myDB,FeedReaderDbHelper.ADDRESS,address);
                        updateStringData(myDB,FeedReaderDbHelper.VOICE_CODE,voiceCode);
                        updateStringData(myDB,FeedReaderDbHelper.USER_PASSWORD,password);
    }
       private void updateStringData(SQLiteDatabase myDB,String columnName,String data){
            try {

                String strSQL = "UPDATE user SET "+columnName+" ='"+data+"' WHERE userName = '"+ userData.userName+"'";

                myDB.execSQL(strSQL);
                myDB.close();

            }catch (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException ex) {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Try to move myDB.close(); after all updateStringData(...);

Comment: thanks,my problem still alive after moving myDB.close() into bottom of updateData()

Comment: What error do you get? How many sql update does not work? Do you get an exception in your log?

Comment: if i use for one update thats well but ones more destroy my activity and first update complete perfectly

Comment: I think problem could be with type of column in sql. Is "mobileNo" field a number? If it is, you have to update your query without quotes.

Comment: here is my query ...  public static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(userName text primary key not null," +  
            USER_PHOTO + " BLOB," +  
            FULL_NAME + " text," +  
            EMAIL_ADDRESS + "email text," + 
            MOBILE_NO + " text," +
            ADDRESS + " text," +
            USER_PASSWORD + " text," +
            VOICE_CODE + " text);";

Answer (score 0):

Where is your userData object? You can set debug point and debug your application to check if anything goes wrong there.

Comment: (here is and i am changing its value from another class.). public class userData {
    public static String userName="";
   public static String FullName="";
   public static String Email="";
  public static String Address="";
   public static String MobileNo="";
    public static byte[] userPhoto=new byte[0];
   public static String voiceCode="";
    public static String password="";
}

Comment: Set a debug point on your query and try to debug it @KmMuzahid .